# Display user informations after identification on Apollo client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm new to Apollo client and I'm currently trying to get the user informations after identification.

Here is my process :

- The user enters its email and password in LoginPage
- A mutation is created by Apollo Client and return jwt token + user (id, firstName, lastName, email).
- The token is saved in localStorage
- The user is redirected to HomePage

I have the following issue :

- How to display user informations in HomePage?

**Here is my LoginPage component :**

```
    class LoginPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            login: true, //switch between Login and SignUp
            email: '',
            password: '',
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            loading: false,
            error: ''
        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(){
        this.setState({loading: true, error: ''});
        this._confirm();
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
          [name]: value
        });
      }

    render(){

        return (
                <div>
                    <div>
                        {this.state.loading ? 
                        <CircularProgress size={60} thickness={7} /> :
                        this.state.login ? 
                            <LoginForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/> 
                            : 
                            <RegisterForm />
                        }
                    </div>
                    {this.state.error ? <div className="error">{this.state.error}</div> : ''}
                    <a
                        onClick={() => this.setState({ login: !this.state.login })}
                    >
                    {this.state.loading ? 
                    '' : this.state.login ? 
                            'Besoin d\'un compte ?' : 'Déjà un compte ?'
                    }
                    </a>
                </div>
        )
    }

    _confirm = ()  => {
      const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = this.state;
      if (this.state.login) {
        this.props.loginMutation({
          variables: {
            email,
            password,
          }
        })
        .then(({data}) => {
          this.setState({loading: false});
          const { token } = data.loginUser;
          this._saveUserData(token);
          checkAuth.authenticate();
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.props.history.push(`/`);
        }).catch((error) => {
          this.setState({loading: false, error: error});
        });
      }
    }

       _saveUserData = (token) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
      }
    }   

    const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql`
        mutation loginMutation($email: String!, $password: String!) {
        loginUser(email: $email, password: $password) {
           token
           user {
            id
            firstName
            lastName
           }
        }
     }
    `

    export default compose(graphql(LOGIN_MUTATION, { name: 'loginMutation' }))(LoginPage)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Some options : query user infos from your server, use your router or redux to pass data, use [the apollo cache](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/caching.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Dyo. I've already tried to use the apollo cache with readQuery (but I can't use it because my login mutation is not stored in the root query) and readFragment without success... 
So I'm currently using jwt-decode to decode the token and extract from it the user id, and then I send the graphql query to the server with the user id to get the informations. That's not (I think) the best solution so if anyone have other examples or solutions which work with the cache that will be really appreciated.

Comment: If you want your userInfo page to handle some mutations you can do the query like you do, you'll have up to date data, btw you should decode the jwt token server side so the client just give the token to query user infos.

Comment: Yes but how I can access to my up-to-date data already present in the store ? Should I have to use fragments for that ? I can see the user data present in the store in apollo web tools so it's frustrating.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you on that, I had some trouble by migrating to Apollo client v2 so I'm not querying the Apollo cache, I use redux to handle the data i want to store.

Comment: Ok no worries I understand your choice, even so thank you for your help Dyo.